# Change search bar and Show position for mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

When I switch to the mobile view the Search bar and Show bar move to the middle of the page. I want them to align to the right of the page. How can I achieve this? I am using the Datatables plugin.

[image]

Code is placed in here https://jsfiddle.net/3k5p2q7g/

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Exception Logs";
}

<div class="content">
    <div class="box box-primary" ng-controller="logController" ng-init="init()">
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <h1>Exception Logs</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="table_Logs">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Time Stamp</th>
                                <th>Exception</th>
                                <th>Message</th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {

    <script src="~/js/site/Logs/LogController.js"></script>

}
```

Comment: I'm understand your Problem but you have n't provide any code for fix..

Comment: I have added HTML code and link to Js file as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) to impact only mobile devices (max-width=767px).

CSS

```
@media max-width: 767px {
    .align-right {
        text-align: right;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="align-right">
    <div class="search">...</div>
    <div class="showbar">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not just search text but also the search text bar.

Comment: I have tried that there is no effect. I am using the DataTables plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media max-width: 767px {
.dataTables_filter, .dataTables_length {
    float:right !important;
}
}
```

Comment: It gave me an error of missing { So I tried this way

@media only screen and (max-width:767px) {
    .dataTables_filter, .dataTables_length {
        float: right;
    }
}

it didn't give an error but there was no effect either.

Comment: @Gullfounder try to add !important

Comment: Nope, it's still the same.

Comment: Which version datatable are you using?

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Comment: I am using version 1.10.16